# Why would I use CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested?

Tags: .net, multithreading, asynchronous, clr

I've got the following sample application:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using static System.Threading.Thread;
using static System.Console;

internal static class ThreadCancellation
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x => Counter(cancellationToken));
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x => CounterWithThrow(cancellationToken));
        Sleep(10);
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        Sleep(10);
    }

    private static void Counter(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        WriteLine($"Counter running on {CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}.");
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            WriteLine($"Thread {CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}:  {DateTime.Now.Ticks}");
            Sleep(1);
        }

        WriteLine("Counter() was canceled");
    }

    private static void CounterWithThrow(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        WriteLine($"CounterWithThrow running on {CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}.");

        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                WriteLine($"Thread {CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}:  {DateTime.Now.Ticks}");
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                Sleep(1);
            }

        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException e)
        {
            WriteLine($"Thread {CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}: Caught OperationCanceledException: {e.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

Which work as I would expect it to and outputs:

```
Counter running on 4.
CounterWithThrow running on 3.
Thread 4:  636619039468459034
Thread 3:  636619039468459034
Thread 4:  636619039468530368
Thread 3:  636619039468530368
Thread 4:  636619039468550400
Counter() was canceled
Thread 3:  636619039468550400
Thread 3: Caught OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
```

Why would I ever chose the `OperationCancelledException` option?

1. Should this really ever be an exception?
2. Tidying up in a `catch` is much harder than doing it gracefully.
3. If I did want to do this, it would be trivial to implement with an `if` statement.

Given that's it's probably there for a good reason, what is that reason?

Comment: Cancellation is normally handled by the client of the `Task`, if you do that you don't need the `try/catch` block within `CounterWithThrow`. If you move your examples into `Task`s then the first will appear to have completed successfully and the second to have been cancelled.

Comment: Thanks @Lee.  I don't really see why that is _better_ though, surely if I'm cancelling a thread then I know I cancelled it.  If I'm writing logic to handle it, then in what way is it even an exception?

Comment: Cancellation is co-operative, so even if you requested the cancellation, you don't know how the task responded to that request unless you check for it. The code handling the cancelled task may not be the same as the one requesting cancellation and may not have access to the token at all.

Comment: @Lee, OK I can sort of see why that might be useful.  `IsCompleted` guarantees that he thread ran _normally_,  it'd still be dangerous to infer anything from cancelled though as it could mean that the thread completed no work, or that it completed all the work?

Comment: @BanksySan, IsCompleted does not guarantee that the task completed 'normally', only that the task is in a final state (RanToCompletion, Faulted or Cancelled).

Comment: @BrianReichle OK, thanks.  I didn't realize (or forget) that was what it signifies.